# Intercept message from specific number in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, cordova, sms, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app using ionic framework. I found cordova-plugin-sms (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) can be used to send sms to a particular number without opening the native app.

I wanted to know if there is a way to use my app to process the text received from one specific number only? i.e, if a message comes from a number +1234, only my app should be able to read it, if a SMS arrives from another number, let the native SMS app handle it.

Comment: not sure without trying it but I would try to use the startWatch method, when a text comes in check the number if it matches toggle intercept on once it is done toggle it back off. could cause issues, or you could recive it on both native and app, save the message from the specific number somewhere else (like a DB) and then delete the message from the phone and repull it in the app from the DB

Comment: @user1692342: have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Any updates on this? :)

Comment: @Marko I haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: Too bad, I'll probably need something like this in future...
If I get anything working I'll post an answer